# Assigning a string to a variable in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to assign the name of a field in a loop to a specific variable in access vba. Then I need this variable to read a specific record from the database. Below you have the piece of code:

```
For n = 0 To numfields - 1
        a = "!" & rst.Fields(n).Name
        If IsNull(!Field1) = False Then
            If n = 1 Then strOutput = strOutput & a
            If n <> 1 And n <> 0 Then strOutput = strOutput & ";" & "!Field" & n
        End If
    Next n
```

The problem is the following: the stored value in the variable would be "!Field(n)" in text and will not get the value from the database in my conditional statement since it's not reading it. Is there any way to convert this text to and actual !Field(n) variable that can read from the database?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you want `a` to store the name of `Fields(n)` or the value which is present in `Fields(n)`?

Comment: Let's say that on the database there is a Field1 and it has a value of "Hello". I want my    Fields(n) to get that value of "Hello". So it would be the value which is present in    Fields(n).

Comment: Then I think you want this: `a = rst.Fields(n).Value`

Comment: Awesome, it worked perfectly! Thank you so much, I appreciate it!

Comment: How do I put it in code in this reply box? I tried before and couldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question. Thanks for your help.

```
For n = 0 To numfields - 1
        a = rst.Fields(n).Value
        If IsNull(!Field1) = False Then
            If n = 1 Then strOutput = strOutput & a
            If n <> 1 And n <> 0 Then strOutput = strOutput & ";" & a
        End If
Next n
```